# How to remove some middle part of hex format string to get new string?

Tags: java, android, string, hex, substring

**STREAM IN HEX:**

*String hexCodeFromBB = "7D44 13 **05 00 06 0E 01 11 13 04 03** 03 00 FE E0 AD AP 06 08 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 14 00 FD 14 02 11 05 01 0C H E G E M O N 1 2 3 4 5 6C C2";*

**Want to change this string to become-**

*String newHexCodeFromBB = "7D44 13 03 00 FE E0 AD AP 06 08 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 14 00 FD 14 02 11 05 01 0C H E G E M O N 1 2 3 4 5 6C C2";*

So all I want is to get rid of those bold bytes from string hexCodeFromBB.

This is what I tried-

```
String codeSplitter[] = hexCodeFromBB.split(" ");

//newHexCodeFromBB = hexCodeFromBB.replace(hexCodeFromBB.substring(2,10),"");

newHexCodeFromBB = hexCodeFromBB.replace(hexCodeFromBB.substring(hexCodeFromBB.indexOf(codeSplitter[2]),hexCodeFromBB.indexOf(codeSplitter[10])),"");
```

This isn't correct.

**I am getting-**

*newHexCodeFromBB = "7D44 13 **03** 03 00 FE E0 AD AP 06 08 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 14 00 FD 14 02 11 05 01 0C H E G E M O N 1 2 3 4 5 6C C2";*

**I thought I missed one (the bold one above) although there is no reason why so I tried-**

```
newHexCodeFromBB = hexCodeFromBB.replace(
         hexCodeFromBB.substring(
            hexCodeFromBB.indexOf(codeSplitter[2]),
            hexCodeFromBB.indexOf(codeSplitter[11])),"");
```

But then again same output.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you're having when swapping from `codeSplitter[10]` to `codeSplitter[11]` is that both of those values contain the same string: `"03"` so the index you're getting from the index of call is the same for both, hence the same output results.

Given this string, your element sizes are 3 characters wide, you have two hex digits and a space. You could solve this solution by finding the index of the last position you want and adding 3 to it, like in this ideone: http://ideone.com/Pem3Bt.

The issue with this, however, is that if you have occurrences of the same type between the start and finish portions of your string - so you'll need to change the way that you calculate your indexes.

**ADDENDUM**

An alternate solution (supposing you're always removing the 2 to the 10th hex section of the string, you could use something like the following here: http://ideone.com/kUQSHc which calculates the indexes for the substring.

```
int start = 2 * 3 + 2;
int end = 11 * 3 + 2;
```

In these calculations, 3 is the number of characters we're skipping over and the `+ 2` is an adjustment because the first "group" of hex characters is 4 characters long instead of 3. I start with the index of the 2nd group, because substrings pull from the start index (inclusively) and I'm using the 11th group start index because substring will stop at the last index (exclusively). This chops the desired portion of the string.

**WARNING**

If you use the method I propose here it makes some assumptions, the most important is that the format of the string of the string will not change. The indexes can change so long as they only ever point to two character groups. You may need to do more discovery on the String to actually calculate the desired locations you really want to cut out.

Comment: Seems to be useful. Will get back after finding what works best or if anything good.

Answer (score 0):

The method `String.substring(beginIndex, endIndex)` includes the value of with index `beginIndex` and excludes the value with index `endIndex`, so add one to the end index.

```
"01234".substring(0,1)=="0"
```

The other issue is with `String.indexOf(str)`: You didn't take into account the length of the second match:

```
"01234".indexOf("23")==2 
"01234".indexOf("2")==2
"01234".indexOf("3")==3
```

So

```
newHexCodeFromBB = 
     hexCodeFromBB.replace(
             hexCodeFromBB.substring(hexCodeFromBB.indexOf(codeSplitter[2]),
             hexCodeFromBB.indexOf(codeSplitter[11]))+codeSplitter[11].length,"");
```

should work

Comment: yes so I put `codeSplitter[11]` instead of `codeSplitter[10]` but without success. Also note that replacing the `hexCodeFromBB.substring(2,10)` with blank will not work here as well.

Comment: Added a second part to explain the problem of `indexOf`